# Python index value as element value

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am using `jinja2` to template a few different types of file reading the values from an `.ini` file.

After loading the values I am trying to loop over the list of tuples I created that matches the element values and using `jinja` resolve the template and stream it to an output file.

`.ini` file example

```
    [COMMON]
    env = example

    [EXAMPLE]
    value1=abc
    value2=xyz
    value3=123
```

list of tuples

```py
    d = [('COMMON', 'env'),
         ('EXAMPLE', 'value1'),
         ('EXAMPLE', 'value2'),
         ('EXAMPLE', 'value3')]
```

Loading `jinja` template

```py
    file_loader = FileSystemLoader(fs)
    e = Environment(loader=file_loader)
    template = e.get_template(tpl)
```

Iterating of list of tuples

```py
    for i in d:
       template.stream(i[1]=parser.get(i[0], i[1])).dump('output.txt')
```

The code fails when trying to use the loop index as the element value which is what I am trying to achieve.
If the element is a matching value of one in the list it works but then I need to have it in both places ie `env=parser.get(i[0], i[1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `stream` method receives arguments as a keyword (`knight` in the example) and value (`'that say nih'` in the example):

```py
template.stream(knights='that say nih')
```

As you can see the keyword is not a Python `string`.

To achieve dynamic passing the template values, you should pass them as a `dict`.
Also, it seems more convenient to unpack `tuple`:

```py
  for key, value in d:
      template.stream({
          value: parser.get(key, value)
      }).dump('output.txt')
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried this but it only resolves the last  value "value3=123" to the template the others remain blank

Comment: In that case I assume that the problem is with your `parser` or with the `.ini` file itself. Could you provide the code of `parser` and check the `.ini` file?

Comment: there should be no spaces around the equal sign

Comment: When I run in debug more I see the parser has the right key value, could it be that .dump() keeps overwriting output.txt and clearing the previously resolved values?

Comment: It sure does, because you dump on each key, value pair and dump is not appending.

Comment: Has the answer helped you?